# Find the MGF of X

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

If $f(x) = (k + 1)x^2$ for $0 < x < 1$. Find the moment generating function of $X$.

Do i do the integral from o to 1 of the above function?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this without comment? This is one of the few introductory problems here on MSE where the OP has at least provided an idea that they have.

Answer (score 1):

The moment generation function $G_X(t)$ is the expectation of $e^{Xt}$. This is 
$$\int_0^1 e^{xt}(k+1)(x^2)\,dx.$$
Note that you will first want to find $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine the $k$ by forcing your distribution to integrate to one over the given interval of $x$, i.e.$$ \int_0^1 \left( k +1 \right) x^2 dx = 1 $$
Solve for $k$ and then proceed by taking the expectation again over that same interval after having plugged in the value of $k$.

Note that all expectations are taken over the probability space of the density function and the MGF is a special case of an expectation.

Comment: Yes $k=2$ and then your density function becomes $3x^2$ for $ 0<x<1$ . Integrate over $[0,1]$ now and you will get $1$. By expectation I meant the MGF though, so the expectation you need to take is $$ 3 \int_0^1  e^{tx} x^2 dx $$ And that will give you the moment generating function of that distribution.

Comment: @Xiong You can try integrating by parts twice.